# ionic and meteor; reset password with a prompt

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, events, meteor, dom-events

I want to reset the user's password, but instead of using the API itself, I want to create a prompt. I am using [meteor-ionic](https://github.com/meteoric/meteor-ionic), and probably want to use one of those prompts shown [here](http://meteor-ionic.meteor.com/popup)

```
Accounts.resetPassword(this.params.token, function() {
  IonPopup.prompt({
    title: 'Create a new password',
    template: 'Please enter your new password',
    okText: 'Submit',
    inputType: 'password',
    inputPlaceholder: 'Your Password',
    onOk: function() {
      return this.password;
    }
  });
}, function(err) {
  Router.go('home');
});
```

However, this will give an error:

> Exception in callback of async function: Error: Match error: Expected string, got function

If I replace `Ion.popup()` with `prompt('please put in password')`, it will work. This leads me to think that the execution isn't halted for the `onOk` function.

How could I use a popup to reset the password with meteor-ionic?

Answer (score 3):

I think that what you need is  something like this:

```
onOk: function(event,response) {
  return response;
```